# Center text on button with hover effect

Tags: html, css, button, text, hover

http://jsfiddle.net/93bphr4f/

html:

```
<button type="button" onClick="location.href='#'" class="buttonpink2">Claim 10 Free Student Accounts for Your School</button>
```

css:

```
/* PINK BUTTON 2 */
.buttonpink2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #b5bcc2;
    border: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: #e57780;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.buttonpink2:after {
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    content: "Claim 10 Free Student Accounts for Your School";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #c24e57;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;

}

.buttonpink2:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.buttonpink2 p {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

look at it,
I dont know why when I hover mouse on button, text move to top..
I want to text be still on center of button.
What i doing wrong?

Anyone can help?

Comment: Your code contains line "Claim 10 Free Student Accounts for Your School" doubled. They have different positioning and when mouse is over button, second instance become visible - during 1s it's opacity changes from 0 to 1 and hides first instance of line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the :after tag at all in this situation.

// All the positioning made the button go crazy.

You should do it this way:

Use .buttonClass { } to set the basic button styling, and use .buttonClass:hover { } to only change the background of the button. You don't have to duplicate every item in the :hover part.

```
/* PINK BUTTON 2 */
.buttonpink2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #b5bcc2;
    border: 0;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #e57780;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.buttonpink2:hover {
    background: #c24e57;
}

.buttonpink2 p {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why you complicated it too much but you simple use `line-height` equal of element height:

```css
/* PINK BUTTON 2 */

.buttonpink2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #b5bcc2;
  border: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: #e57780;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.buttonpink2:after {
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  content: "Claim 10 Free Student Accounts for Your School";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #c24e57;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 75px;/*add line height equal of element height*/
}
.buttonpink2:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.buttonpink2 p {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="location.href='./freeaccess'" class="buttonpink2">Claim 10 Free Student Accounts for Your School</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange way to do, why are you using pseudo-elements just in order to change background-color ?

```
.buttonpink2:after {
    height: 75px;
    line-height:75px;
    ...
}
```

will solve your problem, but I suggest you to remove the `.buttonpink2:after` element and just change the background-color of the button

Comment: He is using the pseudo element to create an animation on hover, not just changing the background color.

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather using padding instead of line-height, you can do this:

```
.buttonpink2:after {
    height: 50%;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some letter-spacing on :after to solve it, I just added 0.3px, you can try other values to make it better.

```css
/* PINK BUTTON 2 */
.buttonpink2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #b5bcc2;
    border: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: #e57780;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.buttonpink2:after {
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    content: "Claim 10 Free Student Accounts for Your School";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #c24e57;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px
}

.buttonpink2:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.buttonpink2 p {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="location.href='#'" class="buttonpink2">Claim 10 Free Student Accounts for Your School</button>
```

Comment: @Kenyon I am using Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) and it works fine.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 38.0.2125.101 64-bit so maybe that's the difference